# minimize byte wasted to align data between 2 headers (custom allocator)

Tags: c++, math, memory-alignment, allocator

Here is a memory layout within a custom allocator :-

```
^ toward less address
....
Header                         [size=16     alignment=4      ] ....(1)
some waste space A             [size=A   (unknown)           ]
content                        [size="SIZE" alignment="ALIGN"] ....(2)
some waste space B             [size=B   (unknown)           ]
Header                         [size=16     alignment=4      ] ....(3)
....
v toward more address
```

The exact address of `Header` is not known beforehand.
However, I know that :-

```
every Header address % 4 == 0      from (1,3)
"content"%ALIGN          == 0      from (2)
```

### Question

How to determine minimum amount of byte for `A+content+B` that make everything (1&2&3) ***always*** align appropriately?

I need the result of the function (`A+content+B`) as a parameter to query a memory block from the custom heap allocator.

```
//return maximum size of A+content+B that make the allocation always safe
int wasteA_content_wasteB(int SIZE,int ALIGN){
    //???
}
```

### My progress

If I approach the problem in a more Mathematic-way :-

```
Header                  start at K1*4
some waste space A      
content                 start at K2*ALIGN
some waste space B       
Header                  start at K3*4
//K1 and K2 and K3 are unknown positive integer
```

I will get an inequality system :-

```
K1*4 + 16     <= K2*ALIGN
K2*ALIGN+SIZE <= K3*4
```

However, with my limited Math background, I don't know how to solve it.

The main difficulty is that I don't know `K1` in advance.

I will know `K1` ***only after*** I get that block of memory.   `:(`

Therefore, the result of function may be a little sub-optimal (for safety at the worst-case), but I think it is acceptable.

### My current workarounds

If I am very desperate, I can :-

1. query a lot more than need e.g. return `ceil((SIZE+max(4,ALIGN)-1)/ALIGN)*ALIGN`
2. brute force every possible combination (e.g. loop by `SIZE` and `ALIGN`) or calculate every case beforehand then cache it inside a text file.

But it is disgraceful ... I believe there is an explicit formula for this problem. (no?)

I would like an answer that shows concept & idea (show how to think).
Code is not required, but I don't mind.

---

3 years later, ***Passer By***'s answer is still useful for me.
So, I will paste my interpretation here :-

[image]
[image]

Comment: Alignment can be achieved actually by a quite simple formula. E.g. align number of bits to 8 (a full byte): `nBitsA = (nBits + 7) / 8 * 8` or even simpler with bit masking: `nBitsA = (nBits + 7) & ~0x7`. Note that the `+ 7` is the trick to round up. The rest is provided for free using integer math.

Comment: I'm (really) not sure whether this is appropriate here but 1st I would try to let the compiler do the work: define a `struct` with the required data layout and then use `sizeof` and, may be, `offsetof`. If the defined `struct` is never instanced this is evaluated by the compiler completely i.e. there will be only "ready computed" constants in the binary code.

Comment: @Scheff Yes, thank!  I use that ceiling trick for ::operator new/delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first assume `ALIGN` is a [power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788262/why-alignment-is-power-of-2).

There are two cases, one is `ALIGN <= 4` and other is `ALIGN > 4`.

If `ALIGN <= 4`, then `content` is always aligned with `A == 0` if `Header` is. All that is left is to pad `B` until the next header is at `alignment == 4`. So, `A + content + B == ceil(content/4)*4`.

If `ALIGN > 4`, we would need to find consecutive bytes where `content` can fit in there with alignment of `ALIGN`.

In the worst case, `Header` can be located at position `k*ALIGN - 12`, and hence `A` would start at `k*ALIGN + 4`. To find an alignment of `ALIGN`, you would need `A == ALIGN - 4`, so `A + content == ALIGN + content - 4`.

What is left is to pad for the next `Header`. `B` starts at `k'*ALIGN + content` and hence we would require `B == 4 - (content%4)` since we assumed `ALIGN` is a power of 2 greater than 4. Thus `A + content + B == ALIGN + content + (content%4)` or `ALIGN + ceil(content/4)*4`.

Note that in this solution, the position of `content` is **not** static relative to `Header`.

Comment: `There are two cases` <-- That is the word of wisdom, so clever.  The whole solution is both accurate and complete.  Thank!